# redireccionar inicio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

estoy en una aplicación de **net core 6**, y estoy tratando de establecer un pagina de inicio diferente al Home, Index;
de la siguiente manera :

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Access}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
```

La idea es que vaya a ese controlador primero y a esa **action**:

una ves que logro hacer funcionar eso, tengo el problema que al menú principal, y tratar de cargar un modulo cualquiera

me deja esta url :  **https://localhost:7233/Home/ManEmpleados**

siendo empleados un controller de la aplicacion, y deberia se de esta manera:  **https://localhost:7233/ManEmpleados**

y la aplicación no carga ManEmpleados por que, no encuentra la pagina.

alguien me podría indicar como solucionarlo???, por que necesito implementar algún sistema de Login en la aplicación...

Esta es la manera en que estoy llamando a los controller de la aplicacion:

```
 <li class="nav-item" id="MenuHome">
     <a class="btn btn-info text-dark"  asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
 </li>

 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
     <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle sm-3" href="#" id="navbarEmpleados" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Mantención de Empleados                                
     </a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarEmpleados">
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="ManEmpleados">Empleados</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="ManDepartamento">Departamento</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="ManCargos">Cargos</a>
         <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="ManCargaFam">Cargas Familiares</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="ManNacionalidad">Nacionalidades</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="ManEmpresa">Empresas</a>                                
     </div>
 </li>
```

Gracias

Comment: Esas son todas las rutas que configuras? Por otro lado el login no debería ser la página por defecto, la pagina por defecto debería ser Home/ManEmpleados por lo que veo. Seguramente en el momento de la redirección después del login estas olvidando colocar el ambso el controller y el action

Comment: Pero en código que has dejado estas definiendo como ruta por defecto a /Access/Login

Comment: si, eso es lo que necesito, para que vaya a login primero, para que el usuario se loguee.

Comment: Estimados, acabo de hace una edición del problema, a ver si me explico mejor

Comment: si, eso es lo que necesito, para que vaya a login primero, para que el usuario se loguee. pero al ejecutar la aplicacion y tratar de cargar un modulo me aparece esto:  https://localhost:7233/Home/ManEmpleados, lo que no es correcto, ojo esto es MVC core 6, no asp.net

Comment: Escribe el código de como creas los links del menu principal porque ahí está el problema, creo que estás poniendo solo el Contrroller en el parámetro donde va el action y no estas incluyendo el action. Por otro lado como te repito el login no deberia ser la pagina por defecto, en su lugar el sistema de autenticacion te debería redireccionar hacia el login si el usuario no estuviera autenticado desde cualquier pagina

Comment: <li class="nav-item" id="MenuHome">
       <a class="btn btn-info text-dark"  asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
   </li>, es como hago para el home

Comment: pero para lo demas uso un control ;   <li class="nav-item dropdown">  de boostap, este editor no me deja mostrar mas codigo

Comment: ademas, por lo que he visto, nunca me ha gustado el sistema de logueo y autenticacion de microsoft

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para popner el código del menú, no en los comentarios., Pero ya te di la respuesta prácticamente, ahí esta el error.

Comment: ya en la pregunta muestro como llamo a los controllers

Comment: yo solucioné un problema así haciendo el menú dinámico desde la vista parcial _layout, entonces, dependiendo del perfil del usuario veo que opciones va a tener y cual va a ser su home del menú, mientras que a la pantalla con la que inicia el sistema, la configuré en los perfiles, por ende tengo el dato y lo puedo redireccionar desde el login.

Comment: saludos, podrías poner un enlace, para ver un ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la misma manera que arriba tienes un `asp-controller` y un `asp-action` para ir al `home/index` de igual manera usa ambos atributos para ir a cada uno de los menus de abajo en lugar de usar `href`

Asumiendo que lo que está en los `href` son los controller y que el action siempre es `Index` (o de lo contrario cámbialo por el valor correspondiente) quedaría algo como:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarEmpleados">
    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="ManEmpleados" asp-action="Index">Empleados</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="ManDepartamento" asp-action="Index">Departamento</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="ManCargos" asp-action="Index">Cargos</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="ManCargaFam" asp-action="Index">Cargas Familiares</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="ManNacionalidad" asp-action="Index">Nacionalidades</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="ManEmpresa" asp-action="Index">Empresas</a>                                
</div>
```

Comment: Genial, muchas Gracias